# How to Count Objects In Android Studio Recylerview

Tags: android, android-studio, object, android-recyclerview, textview

I have opened up all my books and searched High and Low and can't find what I am looking for.

I have a button that will dynamically create textviews in recyler view.  I have also a textview that says please add X more.

I need the textview to count how many textviews are in the recyler view so I can update dynamically the the please add x more.

I just need to be pointed in the right direction on how to update the X More textview with an onchange to the recylerview by counting the number of textview objects in recylerview.

No code to show because I don't know where to start.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Do you mean add 'rows' to the `RecycleView` or do you dynamically add `TextView` to the `RecycleView`?

Comment: I am looking at other samples of something similiar but not quite the same but would I use collections and somehow add all objects from the recylerview to a collection and then count them from the collections?  If so is there a simple example that one can point me to for just counting textviews?

Comment: No, I know how to add textviews dynamically to the recylerview.  What I need to know is how do I count them as they are added so I can update another textview to let the user know how many more thay have to add minimum before they can start.

Comment: I have a button that says ADD PLAYERS.  Then I have below that a recylerview which is initially blank and then below that is the Warning Text View that says Please add 4 more Players. And then below that the start game button.  What I need to do is when the player clicks on add players, it creates a textview in the recycler view and then update the warning textview that says please add 3 more players.  And if delete a player it recounts the textview to update the warning box.  I can do this with a simple counter but I want it to physically count after each addition or deletion of players.

Comment: Then show your code, because I have no idea what you are talking about. Adding a  `TextView` to a `RecyclerView` makes no sense. Adding an Item to the `RecyclerView` that contains a `TextView` does make sense. You add these Items via the `RecyclerView.Adapter` which itself has a property [`getItemCount()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemCount()).

Comment: Yes, adding an item to recylerview that contains textview.  I want to be able to count all the textviews after one is added or removed and update amount in a textview elsewhere.

Comment: I was going to use a scrollview but was told a recylerview is better.  Either way still not sure how to find and count textviews.

Comment: Yes, the `RecyclerView` is a much much better solution than a bastardized `ScollVieww`. -> If all you want to know is how many Items (an Item is basically one element in the `RecyclerView`)  then just use the `getItemCount()`property of the `Adapter` you use to populate the `RecyclerView`. In your code somewhere you need to set the `Adapter` object of the `RecyclerView` like `myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` then to get the number of Items in the `RecyclerView` just do something like `adapter.getItemCount();` ....Done.

Comment: I will give that a shot and post my progress.

Comment: Okay so I have been doing alot of reading and again I am stuck with where to start with this.  I know that I need to have an xml file for the recycler view, and I have seen tons of examples but nothing similiar to what I am looking to do.  So to make things simple.  I have a button that says add player and then a recylerview.  When the add player button is clicked create an textedit in recyclerview to type in players name.  How ever they need to add a minimum of 4 names but can add more.  Not sure where to start with the xml for the recylerview to dynamically add player names.

Comment: This problem is solved thanks to Barns.  Not sure how to accept his answer to have this marked as solved.